# Lua NodeMCU web server connection error (address in use stack traceback)

Tags: lua, webserver, esp8266, nodemcu

I want to turn on and off a led from a web server using NodeMCU but every time I compile the same error occurs. I am in a beginner level so I need some help. I believe this error has something to do with the function listen(). Maybe because I changed my DNS, the port 80 can't be used.

Error:

```
 dofile("ConectarRedeWireless.lua");
  192.168.137.57    255.255.255.0   192.168.137.1
 ConectarRedeWireless.lua:13: address in use
 stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'listen'
 ConectarRedeWireless.lua:13: in main chunk
 [C]: in function 'dofile'
    stdin:1: in main chunk
```

Code:

```
-- Conexao na rede Wifi
wifi.setmode(wifi.STATION)
wifi.sta.config("goncalo","936674888")
print(wifi.sta.getip())
-- Definicoes do pino do led
led1 = 1
gpio.mode(led1, gpio.OUTPUT)
-- Definicoes do Web Server
srv=net.createServer(net.TCP)
srv:listen(80,function(conn)
conn:on("receive", function(client,request)
    local buf = "";
    local _, _, method, path, vars = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+)?(.+) HTTP");
    if(method == nil)then
        _, _, method, path = string.find(request, "([A-Z]+) (.+) HTTP");
    end
    local _GET = {}
    if (vars ~= nil)then
        for k, v in string.gmatch(vars, "(%w+)=(%w+)&*") do
            _GET[k] = v
        end
    end
    buf = buf.."<h1><u>FILIPEFLOP</u></h1>";
    buf = buf.."<h2><i>ESP8266 Web Server</i></h2>";
    buf = buf.."<p><a href=\"?pin=LIGA1\"><button><b>LED 1 LIG</b></button></a> <br/><br/><a href=\"?pin=DESLIGA1\"><button><b>LED 1 DES</b></button></a></p>";
            local _on,_off = "",""
    if(_GET.pin == "LIGA1")then
          gpio.write(led1, gpio.HIGH);
    elseif(_GET.pin == "DESLIGA1")then
          gpio.write(led1, gpio.LOW);
    end
    client:send(buf);
    client:close();
    collectgarbage();
end)
end)
```

Comment: Is this solved? Do you need more feedback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I suggest you use a proper init sequence in which you wait for your device to be fully connected to the WiFi until you set up the server. We keep a [template in our documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/upload/#initlua).

`srv:listen(80,function(conn)` can only be called once for any given port because you can't have multiple server sockets listening on the same port. That's why you get the

> address in use

error. Our [net.server:listen() documentation](https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/en/modules/net/#netserverlisten) shows how to check whether `srv` is available before you listen. You can extend that by running `srv:close()` first before you listen again. Something like this:

```
sv = net.createServer(net.TCP, 30)
if sv then
  sv:close()
  sv:listen(80, function(conn)
    -- do something
  end)
end
```

Btw, where did you get that code sample from? I've seen this several times here on Stack Overflow but it's got more flaws that should be corrected.